# IBM Worklight: Push Notification Device ID

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

There is a field called "device" in deviceSubscription. I assume that it is corresponding to the device ID for the device. And this value is used as a parameter in WL.Server.notifyDevice(userSubscription, device, options) to submit notification for a specific device for a user.

However, when I re-install the apps again, the value in deviceSubscription.device is changed. Therefore, there are different device ID subscribing to an event source although they are actually the same device.

May I know where deviceSubscription.device comes from?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name "Device ID" is indeed confusing. It does not reference the physical device, rather it references to the application. Thus when you re-install the application, you get a different value for it (it is generated by the client-side framework).

Comment: Thanks Idan.
When I re-install the apps (previous subscription was made but no unsubsription was done) and make subscription again, it happens to me that I can receive duplicated notifications by calling WL.Client.notifyAll(eventSource, options). Is there any way to avoid this? Thanks.

Comment: Hah, that would be a design bug in the Push Notifications implementation I would say. :) This is "expected"... and I do not know of a way around it. I have forwarded this information. Thank you!

Comment: Please feel free to drop me a message if there is any update from that.

Comment: By the way, there are some internal tables (NOTIFICATION_USER, NOTIFICATION_DEVICE, etc) which store the notification information. Since there is a need for our application to store the notification information as well, do you suggest us referencing these tables directly? Or it is better for us to maintain another table to store this information while notification message is received on server-side?

Comment: You should not touch those tables.

Comment: Hi Idan, to supplement, when I uninstall the apps (which subscription was made before) and send the notification again after around 5 mins, there is an error "GCM: Device registration ID APA91bF15o6XkXm1uXfYZQaMvzmEb8cctMUx_tInhZRRMHypPuWZtPZu3KOhwkAwOCbrFaSukzlYyQ89DJVVGcZt2G2lzA883GOvZMUlrDb_xxxx rejected by the server (NotRegistered). Subscription deleted.” displayed in Worklight console (the push adapter still returns successful).I think Worklight has some handling to delete the device subscription by this device token. However, I find that the subscription is actually not being deleted.

Comment: Not deleted from where, from Worklight in the database? It sounds to me like the push was successfully sent to the GCM service, there it was rejected because the app was uninstalled (thus removed/got unregistered by the service) and that's why the error was received by GCM.

Comment: Hi Idan, yes, it is not deleted from Worklight database. But it is indicated that "Subscription deleted" (Worklight warning message) from Worklight Console...

Comment: @red23jordan - we have a defect logged for this. Thanks.